# Download many torrents with libtorrent (Python)

Tags: libtorrent

I use libtorrent (python) to download many torrents (about 1500 - from 100mb to several gb). 
I tried different settings but it cannot download more then 4-5 in 24 hours.

May be there are special settings for such tasks?

Here is the last version of code:

set session:

```
async def lt_session(app):
    ses = app['lt_session'] = lt.session({
        'active_downloads': 50,
    })
    ses.listen_on(6881, 6881)
    ses.add_extension('ut_metadata')
    ses.add_extension('smart_ban')
    ses.add_extension('ut_pex')
    ses.add_extension('metadata_transfer')
    ses.start_dht()
    ses.start_lsd()
    app['torrents'] = {}
```

start downloads:

```
async def ensure_downloads_loop(app):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(300)
        try:
            await ensure_downloads(app)
        except:
            pass

async def ensure_downloads(app):
    pool = app['db_pool'][xxx]
    sql = "SELECT post_id FROM xxx WHERE status IN ('new', 'downloading') order by id ASC;"
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor(DictCursor) as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            items = await cur.fetchall()
    result = {
        'downloading': 0,
        'downloaded': 0,
    }
    for item in items:
        id = item['post_id']
        handle = app['torrents'].get(id)
        if handle is None:
            handle = await run_download(app, id)
        done = handle.status().state == lt.torrent_status.seeding
        if not done:
            result['downloading'] += 1
            continue

        pool = app['db_pool'][xxx]
        sql = '''
            UPDATE xxx
            SET status = 'downloaded'
            WHERE post_id = {id};
        '''.format(id=id)
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor(DictCursor) as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()
        if handle:
            app['lt_session'].remove_torrent(handle)
            del app['torrents'][id]
        await check_post_is_done(app, id)
        result['downloaded'] += 1
    return result
```

start downloading torrent:

```
async def run_download(app, id):
    id = int(id)
    pool = app['db_pool'][xxx]
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id = %d;' % id
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor(DictCursor) as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            item = await cur.fetchone()
    ses = app['lt_session']
    path = os.path.join(DOWNLOADS, str(id))
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    params = {'save_path': path}
    handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, item['magnet'], params)
    handle.set_download_limit(-1)
    handle.set_upload_limit(10000)
    app['torrents'][id] = handle
    return handle
```

Comment: you say "it cannot download more then 4-5 in 24 hours.", but you don't really describe the symptom you see. what's preventing it from downloading more or faster? How many torrents do you download in parallel? how many peers do you get? do you have reasons to believe that your client is the bottleneck, as opposed to the peers not being able to upload any faster?

Comment: the main symptom is that I have libtorrent set up with almost default settings (except 'active_downloads': 50), added 1500 magnet links to download - torrents are quite fresh (I tried them in uTorrent and Deluge - they downloaded quite ok). And the result is poor - only 4-5 in 24 hours.
Libtorrent have to check itself peers, connections etc, in order to find active ones and download files, am I wrong?
I suppose that among 1500 torrents there should be more then 4-5 available ones in 24 hours.

Comment: so, what happens to the 45 torrents that are added and "downloading" but are failing to complete? do they find any peers? if not, why not? do they get any responses from trackers? do you have any nodes in your DHT routing table? you may want to take a look at this trouble shooting tree: http://libtorrent.org/troubleshooting.html

Comment: @Arvid, I started 10 torrents in Libtorrent and uTorrent at the same time, looked at network consumption - it was equal (about 10 Mbit for each one). So libtorrent works very nice.
But when I started about 90 torrents in Libtorrent and left them for 24 hours - the result was only 3 downloaded.
May be there are should be special settings for the case when many torrents in the session?

Comment: May be you have examples of code which is intended to load many torrents?

Comment: libtorrent supports a very large number of simultaneous torrents out-of-the box. To find out what's going on you have to look. I gave you some pointers of what to look at

Comment: @Arvid could you please explain, I have such settings: 'active_downloads': 1, 'active_seeds': 0, 'active_limit': 1, 'inactive_down_rate': 2000000. Start first torrent - it loads at low speed, start another torrent - and the second one never starts? Is it normal?

Comment: when 'active_limit' is 2 they both downloading, but shouldn't they rotate when 'active_limit' is 1?

Comment: so, you set `active_limit` to 1, and wonder why you can only download one torrent at a time? You should probably try the default settings